# Jenkins: setting up local Git repository

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, jenkins, virtual-machine

I've just installed Jenkins on a virtual machine using Ubuntu. I'm doing this all locally for the time being. I've set myself up as the administrator and added security features. I wanted to use a local Git repository to test if the system works correctly.

I created a `JenkinsGit` folder in my home directory and added a working `HelloWorld.java` file and a non-working `HelloWorldErr.java` file to see if the system can build and test the 2 files correctly.

I've also installed the Git plugin.

When I create a new item as a Freestyle project, I selected Git for source code management and entered `file:///home/JenkinsGit` as the *Repository URL*, but it gives me the error:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Error performing command: git ls-remote -h file:///home/JenkinsGit HEAD
```

I'm a novice with Linux, Jenkins and Git so I might be missing something pretty obvious here. Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: I've also tried file:///home/<username>/JenkinsGit (as I noticed this should be what the directory is) and still no luck!

Comment: This solved the problem, however, I have now run into a new problem...
After running my test job I get an error message saying `returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: fatal: '/var/lib/jenkins/repo' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

Comment: Nevermind, sorted!